# Validating and grouping excel formula format

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate an excel formula style, with the following regex:

```
=SUM\(((?:\w+\d+)(?::\w+\d+)?)((?:,\w+\d+)(?::\w+\d+)?)*\)
```

On this source:

should pass

```
=SUM(A1,A11:A212,A12:A56,A342:A12,A3)
=SUM(A11:A12,A12:a12,A34:A3)
=SUM(A1,A2,A3)
=SUM(A1)
```

should fail

```
=SUM(A11:A212:A2,A12:A56,A4,A342:A12)
```

And I have the validation part working, but I can't figure out how to group each comma sperated values. They should be:

How I want them to be grouped:

```
=SUM(A1,A11:A12,A12:A56,A3)     // Groups: $1 = A1 $2 = A11:A12 $3 = A12:A56 $4 = A3
=SUM(A11:A12,A10:A12,A34:A3)    // Groups: $1 = A11:A12 $2 = A10:A12 $3 = A34:A3
=SUM(A1,A2,A3)                  //Groups: $1 = A1 $2 = A2 $3 = A3
=SUM(A1)                        //Groups: $1 = A1
```

How they are currently grouped:

```
=SUM(A1,A11:A12,A12:A56,A3)     // Groups: $1 = A1 $2 = A3
=SUM(A11:A12,A10:A12,A34:A3)    // Groups: $1 = A11:A12 $2 = A34:A3
=SUM(A1,A2,A3)                  //Groups: $1 = A1 $2 = A3
=SUM(A1)                        //Groups: $1 = A1
```

Notice, its grouping the first and last. I've pretty new with REGEX so if I'm doing something awful here, please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible: `(...)(?:,(...))+` (2 groups) will always produce 2 matches, no matter how much `+` matches.

You'll need to do it in (at least) 2 steps:

```
value       :=  /\w+\d+(?::\w+\d+)?/

value_list  :=  /value(?:,value)*/

expression  :=  /=SUM\((value_list)\)/
```

Now match group 1 from `expression` (the `value_list`), and find all `value` occurrences in this match.

A quick demo in PHP:

```php
$text = 'should pass

=SUM(A1,A11:A212,A12:A56,A342:A12,A3)
=SUM(A11:A12,A12:a12,A34:A3)
=SUM(A1,A2,A3)
=SUM(A1)

should fail

=SUM(A11:A212:A2,A12:A56,A4,A342:A12)';

$value      = "\w+\d+(?::\w+\d+)?";
$value_list = "$value(?:,$value)*";
$expression = "=SUM\(($value_list)\)";

preg_match_all("/$expression/", $text, $matches);

// iterate over $value_list from $expression (group 1)
foreach($matches[1] as $group1) {
  preg_match_all("/$value/", $group1, $m);
  print_r($m);
}
```

prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => A11:A212
            [2] => A12:A56
            [3] => A342:A12
            [4] => A3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A11:A12
            [1] => A12:a12
            [2] => A34:A3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => A2
            [2] => A3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually split the string first. Something like:

```
sub IsFormulaValid
{
    my $str = $_[0];
    (my $match) = $str =~ /^=SUM\(([^)]+)\)$/;
    my @sumArgs = split(/,\s*/, $match);
    my $valid = 1;
    foreach(@sumArgs){
        if($_ !~ /^[a-z]+\d+(?::[a-z]+\d+){0,1}$/i){
            $valid = 0;
            last;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Note you could also check the match itself for validity, and that @sumArgs > 0 when setting `$valid`.  Test in perl using your input:

```
my @testInput;

push(@testInput,'=SUM(A1,A11:A212,A12:A56,A342:A12,A3)');
push(@testInput,'=SUM(A11:A12,A12:a12,A34:A3)');
push(@testInput,'=SUM(A1,A2,A3)');
push(@testInput,'=SUM(A1)');
push(@testInput,'=SUM(A11:A212:A2,A12:A56,A4,A342:A12)');

foreach(@testInput){
    print "'$_'\n  ";
    print 'NOT ' if !IsFormulaValid($_);
    print "VALID\n\n";
}
```

Results:

```
'=SUM(A1,A11:A212,A12:A56,A342:A12,A3)'
  VALID

'=SUM(A11:A12,A12:a12,A34:A3)'
  VALID

'=SUM(A1,A2,A3)'
  VALID

'=SUM(A1)'
  VALID

'=SUM(A11:A212:A2,A12:A56,A4,A342:A12)'
  NOT VALID
```